# Get each name array and hide each element onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am new to javascript i have this :

```
  $('#spn_inputs').append('<input type="file" name="myfile[] id="fileChooser" /><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="remove-file[]" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">x</a><br/>');

<input type="file" name="myfile[]" id="fileChooser" />
<input type="file" name="myfile[]" id="fileChooser" />
<input type="file" name="myfile[]" id="fileChooser" />
<input type="file" name="myfile[]" id="fileChooser" />
```

I want to loop on each input and delete each when press x:

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="remove-file[]" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">x</a>
```

But this deleting all the inputs , and not only each one , how i do this properly ? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the `inputs` are removed because they are under the same parent. When the parent is removed, then all the `inputs` are also removed too.

One solution is to wrap the `input`, `a` and `br` elements in one unique parent. And onclick do `$(this).parent().remove()`:

```
$('#spn_inputs').append('<span><input type="file" name="myfile[] id="fileChooser" /><a href="javascript:void(0);"  onclick="$(this).parent().remove()">x</a><br/></span>');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fu13ho1f/

Answer (score 0):

No.You can do it like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="remove-file[]" onclick="deleteItem()">x</a>


var deleteItem = function(){
    $(this).remove();
}
```

or you can make click event with javascript.as set click event on each tag with javascript.The `this` inside click event function is the current element you clicked on.
here is a link which can help you.
http://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/javascript-events.html

Comment: That would remove just the `a` tag.  To remove the input too you should call `$(this).previous().remove();` first

Comment: Understood.The you can have each 2 tags (input and a) in one tag (for example div) and then set click event on that div.The "this" will be that "div" which contains one "input" and on "a" tag.how to set event,you can use the link I gave you.

Comment: The problem with that is that the click event will trigger when you click the input too, and he needs to trigger only when the x is clicked.

Comment: but I didn't say you can use $(this).remove().
You can have event on "a" tag and then inside function you must get the element parent (the div) and then remove it.Try anything like this
$(this).parent().remove()

Comment: Right. That would do it  and I think that is a better solution. Having the input and the a tags in a div or span would be better.

Comment: Well this is not working , also i can't do you'r way instead i did : function deleteItem(){
    $(this).remove();
}  but not working

Comment: I think you didn't understand me